# PHP composer, use package specifying 5.3.7, on 5.3.3-7+squeeze19

Tags: php, composer-php, php-5.3

In my case I'm trying to use the composer package "jeremykendall/password-validator" on a server that currently requires i use php 5.3.3-7+squeeze19.

But this lib requires php 5.3.7.

Any ideas of how I could get around this? or test if it works?

I'm thinking I could fork the lib to test, but does anyone know any composer features that could help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library in question has a test suite. Simply run its tests on your 5.3.3 box and if they work you can be more confident in using it.

I would speculate that they might not: the author must have a good reason for specifying that particular version of PHP. There may be a bugfix in 5.3.7 that part of the library depends on.

In that case, I would suggest you write a couple of your own unit tests to ensure the parts of your code that use the library still work on that environment.

Comment: Thanks @bcmcfc, I was about to try this but then the other answer came in and explained I shouldn't bother for this use case due to the php bug. But I'm marking this as the correct answer as in other cases for checking if a lib can work this is the correct method thanks!

Comment: Actually, this answer suggests "try running the tests, they hopefully will fail if they test for a PHP bug or feature, and then..." - you still cannot use Composer to add the library, and you must hope that the tests do cover the bug or feature. I do like the other answer more.

Comment: @Sven the question asks "how can I get around this, or test if it works". Since it can't be gotten around, the latter can at least be answered.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suspect the reason for the requirements is the same as for [ircmaxell's more famous password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat#requirements):

> ## Requirements
>
> This library requires `PHP >= 5.3.7` OR a version that has the `$2y`
>   fix backported into it (such as RedHat provides). Note that Debian's
>   5.3.3 version is **NOT** supported.
>
> The runtime checks have been removed due to this version issue. To see
>   if password_compat is available for your system, run the included
>   `version-test.php`. If it outputs "Pass", you can safely use the
>   library. If not, you cannot.
>
> If you attempt to use password-compat on an unsupported version,
>   attempts to create or verify hashes will return `false`. You have been
>   warned!
>
> The reason for this is that PHP prior to 5.3.7 contains a [security
>   issue with its BCRYPT
>   implementation](http://php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php).
>   Therefore, it's highly recommended that you upgrade to a newer version
>   of PHP prior to using this layer.

It sounds like your 5.3.3 version does *not* have the backport fix (based on that it looks Debian based, confirm yourself if the fix has been backported specifically to your version or not), so you really shouldn't be running this code (or any bcrypt based code) on 5.3.3 as it may open you up to actual security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks @deceze, I'd hadn't seen about this. I'll leave integrating this then until this older server can be upgraded.

Comment: @stilliard: This is the correct answer. My lib is really just a convenience wrapper around password_compat, so those requirements are my requirements.

Comment: Hi @Jeremy Kendal, this is the correct answer specificity based on the use of this lib. I marked it as the other one though mainly as for other libs i'd of gone with the other answer and so if someone came here based on the question name, the other answer seemed more appropriate.
I could always edit the question description though to be a bit more generic though.

Comment: @JeremyKendall technically speaking they're both correct - one is general and one is specific. Both would help future searchers looking for one or the other, as stilliard suggests.